# How to Pass nested table into sub procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

In below code am trying to pass nestedTable payment_obj from parent procedure to child procedure, but in child procedure am not able to insert data into nested table as it is throwing even after initialization in parent procedure ERROR- Reference to uninitialized collection"
*Cause:    An element or member function of a nested table or varray
           was referenced (where an initialized collection is needed)
           without the collection having been initialized.

I am collecting data into nested table which need to insert into payment table in child procedure and inserting data into payment table that is collected in nested table in parent procedure. How to achieve this type of requirement if it is not possible with nested table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE pkg_payment
AS
PROCEDURE PROCESS_PAYMENTS;
END pkg_payment;

CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE body pkg_payment
AS
type typ_payment
IS
  record
  (
    payment_id payment1.payment_id%type,
    );
type tab_typ_payment
IS
  TABLE OF typ_payment;
PROCEDURE prepare_payments(payment_obj OUT tab_typ_payment )
IS
  tab_typ_payment_INDEX NUMBER ( 2 ) := 0 ;

BEGIN
  payment_obj.extend;
tab_typ_payment_INDEX:= payment_obj.count;
  payment_obj ( tab_typ_payment_INDEX ) .payment_id :=tab_typ_payment_INDEX;

END prepare_payments;

PROCEDURE PROCESS_PAYMENTS
IS
  payment_obj tab_typ_payment:= tab_typ_payment();
CURSOR C_PUIDS_CUR
  IS
    (
    select puid from payments
    );
type PUIDS
IS
  TABLE OF C_PUIDS_CUR%rowtype;
PUIDS_OBJ PUIDS := PUIDS();
BEGIN
  OPEN C_PUIDS_CUR;
  LOOP
    FETCH C_PUIDS_CUR bulk collect INTO PUIDS_OBJ limit 100;
    BEGIN
      FOR I_ROW_PUID IN 1 .. PUIDS_OBJ .count
      LOOP
         prepare_payments( payment_obj);
      END LOOP; -- FOR LOOP
    END;        -- END for fetch begin
    EXIT
  WHEN C_PUIDS_CUR %notfound;
  END LOOP; -- End for limit loop
  CLOSE C_PUIDS_CUR ;
  forall i IN 1 .. payment_obj.count SAVE EXCEPTIONS
  INSERT INTO payment1 VALUES payment_obj
    (i
    );
END PROCESS_PAYMENTS;
END pkg_payment;
```

Answer (score 0):

Procedure `prepare_payments` needs to initialise `payment_obj`.

I'm not sure what this is all meant to do, but the following runs without error:

```
create table payment1 (payment_id number);
create table payments (puid integer);

insert into payments (puid) values (1);

create or replace package pkg_payment
as
    procedure process_payments;
end pkg_payment;
/

create or replace package body pkg_payment as
    type typ_payment is record
    ( payment_id payment1.payment_id%type );

    type tab_typ_payment is table of typ_payment;

    procedure prepare_payments
        ( payment_obj out tab_typ_payment )
    is
        tab_typ_payment_index number(2) := 0;
    begin
        payment_obj := tab_typ_payment();  -- Initialised here
        payment_obj.extend;
        tab_typ_payment_index := payment_obj.count;
        payment_obj(tab_typ_payment_index).payment_id := tab_typ_payment_index;
    end prepare_payments;


    procedure process_payments is
        payment_obj tab_typ_payment := tab_typ_payment();

        cursor c_puids_cur is
            select puid from payments;

        type puids is table of c_puids_cur%rowtype;
        puids_obj puids := puids();
    begin
        open c_puids_cur;
        loop
            fetch c_puids_cur bulk collect into puids_obj limit 100;

            for i_row_puid in 1 .. puids_obj.count loop
                prepare_payments(payment_obj);
            end loop;

            exit when c_puids_cur%notfound;
        end loop;

        close c_puids_cur;

        forall i in 1 .. payment_obj.count save exceptions
            insert into payment1 values payment_obj (i);

    end process_payments;
end pkg_payment;
```